# What is "old sys" exactly and why would I receive errors in 2012 because of a missing Macro?

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012, axapta

I'm receiving this error in an AX 2012 upgrade environment:

`Unable to compile int convert(){#SysBPCheck return #BPErrorSecurityKeyNotConnected;}.`

And I've tracked it down to the macro `#SysBPCheck` missing `#BPErrorSecurityKeyNotConnected`.

The macro is unmodified, and if I use the compare tool, I see "sys" and "old sys".  And it exists in Old Sys.  How/why would this get blown away and not work?  I've done a full compile, but not a CIL compile.  What is "Old Sys" exactly anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Old sys" is the previous version of the object created due to an upgrade. In previous AX versions (previous to 2012), there were in the /old folder (you can move layer files manually into this folder before updating, so you can compare objects with previous version) inside the application folder (/app). Since AX 2012 it should be in the BaseLine database that is created during install and you can import old .ald files into this database (through upgrade tools) to compare actual 2012 objects with you old version objects.

Those errors are from internal kernel objects. You should run a full kernel compilation, including a full CIL compilation if you haven't done it yet with this command line:

```
    ax32.exe -StartupCmd=KernelCompileAll
```